# php how to execute function on session timeout

Tags: php, authentication, session-state, session-timeout

I have `$_SESSION` variables containing user login username that have the default session life set ( 24 minutes I think ).  I'm wondering if there is a way to execute a function on session timeout.

I know I can tell the page to execute the function when the user reloads the page and the session variable has expired but I'm trying to figure out a way for the server to do this by itself.  Is there such a method?

**My Reasoning**:  When the user logs in I report to my database and update the user record for 'lastlogin'.  I want to update 'lastlogout' when the user clicks logout or when the `$_SESSION` variable expires.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try settings callbacks in [session_set_save_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) on close and gc (garbage collector).

Comment: I have not tried this yet but it sounds promising, thanks for the input.

Answer (score -1):

You can use javascript for this in about this way:

```
<?php

...
$currentTimeoutInMillis = ini_get(’session.gc_maxlifetime’) * 1000;

print "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
print "<!--\n";
print "setTimeout('window.location.href=\"timeout.php\"', $currentTimeoutInMillis);\n";
print "//-->\n";
...

?>
```

Then your `timeout.php` will be called automatically when the timeout period is exhausted. In this script, by this time, the $_SESSION content is already lost (garbage-collected) - and you can make your database calls to update user's record.

Comment: True, it won't work if the window is closed.  Frankly, I'm not sure if you can do anything once the window is closed though.